# Need a way to subscribe to an observable that Angular service holds and also display it in view

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am writing an angular + nodejs application where server listens to twitter stream and front-end angular application using socket.io gets data from server. Everything works till this point, but I am unable to find a way to subscribe to my angular service which using socket.io gets the data. How can I subscribe to the data that my service has and also how can I bind it to my view, so that the data shows up.

Here is my service code in Angular that gets data from server:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class twitterService {
    socket = null;
    tweets$: Observable<string[]>;
    private _tweetObserver : Observer<string>;
    constructor(){
        this.tweets$ = new Observable(observer => this._tweetObserver = observer);
    }
    getTweets() {
        var tweetText: string;
        this.socket = io('http://localhost:8383');
        this.socket.on('twit', function(data){
            tweetText = data; 
        });
        this._tweetObserver.next(tweetText);
    }
}
```

And here is my Component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {twitterService} from '../Services/Twitter/twitterService';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Component({
    selector: 'social',
    viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    providers: [twitterService],
    templateUrl: './components/app/social/social.html'
})
export class socialComponent {
    public tweetsObserver: Observer<string>;
    public tweets$:Observable<string>;
    public tweetsData:string[] = ["Red", "Yellow"];
    items: Array<string>;
    constructor(http: Http, tweets:twitterService) {
        tweets.tweets$.subscribe(tweets => this.items = tweets);
        tweets.getTweets();
    }
}
```

And here is my view code:

```
<li *ngFor="#item of items | async">{{item}}</li>
```

Comment: Would be great to see the code of your service and how the observable is exposed.

Comment: Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/xQW34EXP

Comment: Please edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Doesn't look too bad. What is not working as expected?

Comment: I am unable to show the data on the view. How can I bind the observable from component to the view.

Comment: What's the problem? Why can't you bind to `items`? How is the items data structured? How should they be displayed?

Comment: If you want to display all incoming data, then add them to an array and bind to that array.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to directly bind using the observable itself. But it isn't working. I just added my view code as well.

Comment: What or how does the observable provide the data? All at once or a continuous stream of data?

Comment: It is continuous stream.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107421/discussion-between-ram-v-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement this feature this way:

```
@Injectable()
export class twitterService {
  socket = null;
  tweets$: Observable<string[]>;
  private _tweetObserver : Observer<string>;
  tweets: string[];

  constructor(){
    this.tweets$ = new Observable(observer => this._tweetObserver = observer);
  }

  getTweets() {
    var tweetText: string;
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:8383');
    this.socket.on('twit', (data) =>{
        this.tweets.push(data);
        this._tweetObserver.next(this.tweets); 
    });
  }
}
```

This way time a twit is received, the list of twits will be updated in your component. This way you can still use the async operator.

You could also implement such processing in your component and not in the service.

```
@Injectable()
export class twitterService {
  socket = null;
  tweet$: Observable<string>;
  private _tweetObserver : Observer<string>;

  constructor(){
    this.tweet$ = new Observable(observer => this._tweetObserver = observer);
  }

  getTweets() {
    var tweetText: string;
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:8383');
    this.socket.on('twit', (data) =>{
        this._tweetObserver.next(data); 
    });
  }
}
```

and the component:

```
service.$tweet.subscribe((newTwit) => {
  this.tweets.push(newTwit);
});
```

In this case, this.tweets corresponds a simple array (not an observable) and you don't need to use the async pipe in your ngFor.

Comment: Awesome. The 2nd solution did work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I got a error "Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'. Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'."  on this     this.tweet$ = new Observable(observer => this._tweetObserver = observer);
why is that

Answer (score 1):

Collect the tweets in an array and use `*ngFor="#tweet of tweets"` to bind to the array:

```
tweets.tweets$.subscribe(tweets => this.items = this.items.concat(tweets));
```

ohne `| async`

```
<li *ngFor="#item of items">{{item}}</li>
```

Comment: This didn't help. I tried pushing the data to array but still the view isn't getting updated.

Comment: try smth like `tweets.tweets$.reduce((acc, next) => acc.concat([next]), [])` or  `tweets.tweets$.scan((acc, next) => acc.concat([next]), [])` for collect your data to array incremental `scan` or if your observable has been completed `reduce`.

Comment: Also use some wrapper `fromSocket` or `fromEvent(socket, 'eventName')`