# Angular2 : Can't subscribe to an observable

Tags: angular, websocket, components

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238363/need-a-way-to-subscribe-to-an-observable-that-angular2-service-holds-and-also-di) is similar but I still can't get this working even after reading it and a number of tutorials and examples.  It seems that there are a lot of different styles and approaches to Angular 2.

I'm trying to get an Angular 2 component to listen to a service that will be receiving tweets over a web socket.

Right now I just want to get the most recent Tweet that I received on the socket.

Tweets are arriving on the socket and my console log is showing that I'm "Setting message" every time I "Got message".  The tweets are an object with a key "message" containing the string of the twit.

The "change" log message in the component is not appearing, so I'm assuming that there is a problem subscribing to the subject.

I just can't spot it, though, I have read some of the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) and tried those patterns but I still can't get it working.

I have this service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Rx from "rxjs/Rx";

declare var Phoenix: any;

@Injectable()
export class PhoenixChannelService {

    socket: any;

    private myMessage: string;

    private messageSubject: Rx.Subject<string> = new Rx.Subject<string>();

    constructor() {

        this.socket = new Phoenix.Socket("ws://localhost:4000/socket", {
            logger: ((kind, msg, data) => { console.log(`${kind}: ${msg}`, data) }),
            transport: WebSocket
        });
        this.socket.connect();
        this.socket.onError( () => console.log("there was an error with the connection!") );
        this.socket.onClose( () => console.log("the connection dropped") );
    }

    public subscribeToKeyword(submittedKeyword) {
        let channel = this.socket.channel("keyword:" + submittedKeyword, {token: "foo"})
        var me = this;
        channel.on("tweet", function(msg) {
            console.log("Got message", msg);
            me.setMessage(msg.message);
        });
        channel.join()
            .receive("ok", ({messages}) => console.log("catching up", messages) )
            .receive("error", ({reason}) => console.log("failed join", reason) )
            .receive("timeout", () => console.log("Networking issue. Still waiting...") )
    }

    public getMessage(): Rx.Observable<string> {
        return this.messageSubject.asObservable();
    }

    setMessage(message: string): void {
        console.log("Setting message");
        this.myMessage = message;
        this.messageSubject.next(message);
    }

}
```

And this is my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PhoenixChannelService } from './app.phoenix_channels.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'watch-stream',
    templateUrl: 'templates/stream.html',
    providers: [PhoenixChannelService]
})
export class StreamComponent {

    currentMessage: string;

    constructor(private phoenixChannel: PhoenixChannelService) {

        phoenixChannel.getMessage().subscribe((newMessage: string) => {
            console.log("change");
            this.currentMessage = newMessage;
        });

        console.log('Constructed the stream component');

    }


}
```

Comment: Do i miss something or isnt the subscribe method called in the PhoenixChannelService. Also it's better to rename it to something like subscribeToKeyword(keyword). So you can't be confused with the default subscribe method. Also its better to use the new arrow functions in ecmascript 6 and use a transpiler. (built in by angular-cli). On everything else I can't see something thats wrong with your code. You also try to set a error block in the StreamComponent to figure out if you got any errors.

Comment: Thanks, I renamed the service subscribe() method to subscribeToKeyword()